# No funciona ScrollPane en mi JTable en java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Amigos, un gusto saludarlos, quería preguntarles por que mi `JscrollPane` no funciona, esto es lo que tengo en mi método donde construyo mi tabla:

```
private void construirTabla(){
        String data [][]={};    
        String col[]={"CVE_TIPO_VALOR","CVE_INSTRUMENTO",
                "CVE_SERIE","NUM_ORDEN","OPCIONAL", "FechaRegistro",
                "FECHA_EXCUPON","FECHA_PAGO","FECHA_PAGO","OPCIONAL",
                "FECHA_APLICACION","TIPO_DERECHO", "MONTO_DERECHO", 
                "MONTO_NETO", "CVE_MONEDA", "MONTO_DERECHO", "CVE_MONEDA",
                "MONTO_NETO", "CVE_MONEDA", "FEE_DERECHO", 
                "TITULOS_NUEVOS", "TITULOS_ANTERIORES", "ES_REGIMEN_FISCAL", 
                "FECHA_CARTERA", "FECHA_FIN_REVALUACION", "FECHA_MODIFICACION",
                "METODO_CAMBIO", "METODO_REDONDEO", "ORIGEN_DERECHO", 
                "PORC_COSTO_ANTERIOR", "REDONDEO_TITULOS"};

        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
        miTabla1.setModel(modelo);
        miTabla1.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Aqui es donde creo el jtable y el JscrollPane:

```
JTable miTabla1 = new JTable(modelo);
    JScrollPane miBarra = new JScrollPane(miTabla1);
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando cargo la información de las columnas me aparecen todo amontonado, apenas estoy aprendiendo de Swing y no sé exactamente como hacerlo, les dejo una imagen de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar con este, se los agradecería de corazon, quedo al pendiente si algo me hace, pero creo que con lo que puse sería suficiente

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude solucionar agregue estos códigos:

```
miBarra.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
        miBarra.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        miTabla1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        miTabla1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Y me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero utilizar este codigo:

```
miTabla1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

Según lo que entiendo es que lo que hace es ajustarse en automático las columnas pero parece ser que no funciona, alguien sabe como se podría corregir el tamaño adecuado a las columnas?

Comment: tal vez mejore si pruebas agregarle `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize` a tu tabla

Comment: El `AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS` le indica a la tabla que debe ajustar el tamaño de sus columnas para que no ocupen más espacio que el tamaño de su contenedor. Por lo que no lo puedes utilizar si quieres un scroll horizontal.